# How to perform merge operation between two Eclipse resources programmatically

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-emf, emf

As of now I have two Eclipse resources objects(org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.Resource), now I want to implement merge operation between both resource objects using emf.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare and merge EMF models using [EMF-Compare](https://www.eclipse.org/emf/compare/).

Code snippet from the [FAQ](https://www.eclipse.org/emf/compare/documentation/latest/FAQ.html#How_can_I_use_EMF_Compare_programmatically_.3F), to launch EMF-Compare programmatically :

```
public void compare(File model1, File model2) {
    URI uri1 = URI.createFileURI("path/to/first/model.xmi");
    URI uri2 = URI.createFileURI("path/to/second/model.xmi");

    Resource.Factory.Registry.INSTANCE.getExtensionToFactoryMap().put("xmi", new XMIResourceFactoryImpl());

    ResourceSet resourceSet1 = new ResourceSetImpl();
    ResourceSet resourceSet2 = new ResourceSetImpl();

    resourceSet1.getResource(uri1, true);
    resourceSet2.getResource(uri2, true);

    IComparisonScope scope = new DefaultComparisonScope(resourceSet1, resourceSet2);
    Comparison comparison = EMFCompare.builder().build().compare(scope);

    List<Diff> differences = comparison.getDifferences();
    // Let's merge every single diff
    IMerger.Registry mergerRegistry = new IMerger.RegistryImpl();
    IBatchMerger merger = new BatchMerger(mergerRegistry);
    merger.copyAllLeftToRight(differences, new BasicMonitor());
}
```